Bluetooth audio not working on 24.04
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.1. I was originally using Pulseaudio on 22.04 and audio worked great. Upgrading to 24.04.1 replaced Pulseaudio with Pipewire and broke audio. I installed Pulseaudio instead. It works great, besides the fact that the Bluetooth speakers that I have connected are not showing up in my audio settings. It shows my headset, monitor, and laptop speakers, but not the BT speakers.
radi8@framework:~$ bluetoothctl devices
Device 41:42:A7:25:26:B9 BESTISAN SR02

Screenshot of GNOME settings not showing bluetooth speaker
Screenshot of bluetooth settings showing speaker is connected
Help would be appreciated!

I had similar issue and generally prefer ALSA, but do have pipewire and pulseaudio, as I do like to change at times If i find in a different way not working right, but audio with my bluetooth Bose speaker, is great both with pulseaudio or pipewire and ALSA as well, if i choose the pusleaudio to pipewire or vice versa, or just alsa, just depends on certain conditions I sometimes encounter, like strange dips and ups of the audio sound level.. It didn't necessarily break mine, as I installed the minimal version of xubuntu 24.04 Live USB disk. you may wanna try if you got the bluetooth stuff installed from either the upgrade or live disk way if it wasn't the minimal version of it, as some of the defaults aren't always the best, so yes uninstall all bluetooth stuff you have now, and once you do reboot just to be sure then do the next steps., Now I use an USB dongle for bluetooth capability, is yours that or internal in the PC? Hopefully too you will use a package manager, like Synaptic for this, to help you as to be specific in choosing, not everything is needed. What you choose though, it'll also install anything else it needs as well but first try these 3 first.
blueman -- Blueman is a GTK+ bluetooth management utility for GNOME using bluez D-Bus
backend. , then
bluez - This package contains tools and system daemons for using Bluetooth devices.
BlueZ is the official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack. It is an Open Source
project distributed under GNU General Public License (GPL). ,
and last,
bluez-alsa-utils - Bluetooth Audio ALSA Backend allow bluetooth audio without PulseAudio.
then,
bluez-alsa-utils  -  This project is a rebirth of a direct integration between Bluez and ALSA.
Since Bluez >= 5, the build-in integration has been removed in favor of 3rd
party audio applications. From now on, Bluez acts as a middleware between an
audio application, which implements Bluetooth audio profile, and a Bluetooth audio device.
This package contains files that is tool using bluez-alsa plugin.
then.  DO hope this will work for you, but yes we may just have to try different options if this doesn't work.
